# Is there a WP CLI hook for handling ctrl+c

Tags: wp-cli

I know there are hooks for writing custom commands as found here: https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/references/internal-api/wp-cli-add-hook/

In my case, I want to handle cleaning up on exit (Ctrl+C) or any SIGKILL signal. Is there a way to handle this in custom WordPress cli?